# PyQt5 - stuck in a loop while trying to close ui using macOS

Tags: python, loops, pyqt5

I have created a UI with PyQt5. I can use it on Windows and it works perfectly, but when I try to use it on MacOS I get stuck trying to close it (with `self.close()`). Using the PyCharm debugger I found out that after `self.close()` it jumps to `app.exec_()` and the function that was entered to close it is executed again (for example `on_later_button_clicked(self)`). I have also already tried `sys.exit(app.exec_())`.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from Modules.database import addNeverID
from Modules.supportedWebsites import getWebsites


def Start():
    m = askForPartnerUrl()
    # m.setFixedSize(500,500)
    m.show()
    return m


class askForPartnerUrl(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(askForPartnerUrl, self).__init__()
        loadUi('lib/askForPartnerURL.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Upload')

        current_id = getFromFile("id.txt")

        self.show_id.setText(current_id)
        self.show_origin_url.setText(
            '<a href="' + getFromFile("origin_url.txt") + '">' + getFromFile("origin_url.txt") + '</a>')
        self.show_origin_url.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        id_beginns = ["1"]
        website_eq = ["1"]

        website_guess_str = "Nicht verfügbar!"

        for i in range(len(id_beginns)):
            if id_beginns[i] in current_id:
                website_guess_str = '<a href="http://' + website_eq[i] + '">' + website_eq[i] + '</a>'
                self.website_guess.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
                break

        self.website_guess.setText(website_guess_str)

        self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.on_save_button_clicked)
        self.later_button.clicked.connect(self.on_later_button_clicked)
        self.never_button.clicked.connect(self.on_never_button_clicked)

        try:
            os.remove('temp/currentObject/partner_url.txt')
        except:
            pass

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_never_button_clicked(self):
        addNeverID(getFromFile("id.txt"))
        saveToFile("Never-ID", "partner_url.txt")
        self.close()

    def on_later_button_clicked(self):
        saveToFile("Later-ID", "partner_url.txt")
        self.close()

    def on_save_button_clicked(self):

        url_is_valid = False

        for i in getWebsites():
            if i in self.partner_url_input.text():
                url_is_valid = True
                break

        if url_is_valid:
            saveToFile(self.partner_url_input.text(), "partner_url.txt")
            self.close()
        else:
            error_dialog = QtWidgets.QErrorMessage(self)
            error_dialog.setWindowTitle("Eingabe nicht verwertbar")
            error_dialog.showMessage('Die eingegebene URL ist nicht verwendbar! Bitte prüfe deine Eingabe.')


def showGUI():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('lib/icon.png'))
    window = Start()
    app.exec_()


def saveToFile(content, filename):
    file = open("temp/currentObject/" + filename, "w+")
    file.write(content)
    file.close()


def getFromFile(filename):
    file = open("temp/currentObject/" + filename)
    content = file.read()
    file.close()
    return content
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that since you're using uic, it automatically enables the auto-connection feature, which automatically detects function names based on object/signals names and connects them, *even if the functions do not have Qt slots decorators*.

The result is that your slot will be actually called *thrice*:

1. without any argument (`clicked()`);
2. with the `checked` argument (`clicked(bool)`): the argument is ignored by Qt since the function doesn't take any, but the function will be called *anyway* because no slot signature has been specified for it;
3. again with the `checked` argument, because you manually connected it in your code;

If you want to keep using the auto connection, use a unique slot decorator for *that* specific function, otherwise manually connect to a function (possibly with a slot, if you need a specific signature) that does *not* use the auto connection naming, but **don't** use both.

```
class askForPartnerUrl(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(askForPartnerUrl, self).__init__()
        loadUi('askForPartnerURL.ui', self)

        # ...

        # remove the following lines:
        # self.save_button.clicked.connect(self.on_save_button_clicked)
        # self.later_button.clicked.connect(self.on_later_button_clicked)
        # self.never_button.clicked.connect(self.on_never_button_clicked)

        # manual connection
        self.later_button.clicked.connect(self.saveLater)

    # using the auto connection; the function doesn't need arguments, so
    # you can ignore the argument type signature
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_never_button_clicked(self):
        addNeverID(getFromFile("id.txt"))
        # ...

    # with a normal function; in this case no slot decorator is required since
    # you don't have arguments
    def saveLater(self):
        url_is_valid = False
        # ...
```

PS: The reason for which it gets "stuck" is probably due to the way Python deals with the end of the program (which by default happens as soon as the last window is closed in Qt) on MacOS: after the first call to `close()` PyQt tries to quit the QApplication (free up memory, etc...), but while doing so the original click event is still in the process of firing the signals to the remaining second and third slot, hence the "loop" (but it's not an actual loop, and the third slot never gets called because it's the second one that blocks everything).
Note that this is a *big* oversimplification, I'm not an expert in memory usage and low level programming, but this is fundamentally what's happening.